# OCaml standard Map vs. Jane Street Core.std Map

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

So I'm using Jane Street's Core.std for certain things in my program but still want to use the standard OCaml Map.  However, when I call functions like `mem`, it expects the signature of the Core.std version.  How do I get past this hurdle?

```
open Core.Std
open Map

module PortTable = Map.Make(String)
let portTable = PortTable.empty 
let string_add = (Int64.to_string packet.dlDst) in 
PortTable.mem string_add portTable
```

This will not compile for me, as it's expecting Core.std's version of `mem`, not the standard one:

> Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
> 'a PortTable.t = (string, 'a, PortTable.Key.comparator_witness) t

I just want to use the standard one. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Core.Std` library exposes the standard library via the `Caml` module, thus, you can access any value from the standard library by just prefixing its name with `Caml.` e.g.,

```
module PortableMap = Caml.Map.Make(String)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one suggestion:

```
module StdMap = Map
open Core.Std

module PortTable = StdMap.Make(String)
```

Here's a session excerpt that shows how it works:

```
# module PortTable = StdMap.Make(String);;
module PortTable :
  sig
    type key = Core.Std.String.t
    type 'a t = 'a Map.Make(Core.Std.String).t
    val empty : 'a t
    val is_empty : 'a t -> bool
    val mem : key -> 'a t -> bool
    ...
  end
#
```

Note that `PortTable` is created from the standard OCaml Map.Make functor, but `String` is the one from Core. You could use a similar trick to retain a name for the standard OCaml String module.

(Personally, I wouldn't open the `StdMap` module; the namespace is already pretty crowded.)

Comment: Local opens might be worthwhile here too instead of globally opening a module in a file, especially when a module has a crowded namespace

Comment: @NickZuber, the Core library is designed in such way, you should open Core.Std, as it is an overlay over a standard library.

Comment: @ivg I was referring to the Map module here

Comment: ah, I see, you meant the `open Map` in the OP post.